# Android FFmpeg convert on the fly

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using `ffmpeg` library in my project with custom VideoPlayer. I can convert video from .avi to .mp4, but it takes more time to convert. Can I convert video on the fly using `ffmpeg`?

**EDIT**
So I want to play videos with different formats, that standard MediaPlayer doesn't support now. I've built `ffmpeg` for my project, now I have ffmpeg.so file and I can convert video through `ffmpeg`, for example:

```
ffmpeg input.avi -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec aac -strict -2 output.mp4
```

But it can spend more time, if video is big. How can I realize different formats support using `ffmpeg`?

Comment: I want to start converting and simultaneously playing this video (.mp4), maybe with minimum delay.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can convert video on the fly using ffmpeg (it would actually be called *transcoding*).

Here's an older [guide](http://linuxers.org/tutorial/basic-video-transcoding-options-ffmpeg) written for linux.  All of it should still work on Android.

Comment: This is not, that I need. As I understood in this guide, video must be already converted, so ffmeg transcode video from one format to another, both files will be saved and I can start playing after transcoding will be finished. Is it really start playing new video and transcoding simultaneously, maybe with a few seconds delay?